# How to enable jetpack deeplink without a slash "/" in the deeplink pattern

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack

I have a short question here, why when I use deeplink in jetpack navigation, I have to add a "/" in the deeplink pattern.

For example, it will work (a dialog shows to ask do I want to open in browser or the app) when I use "www.example.com/" as the pattern.

Inside nav graph:

```
<deepLink app:uri="www.example.com/" />
```

and then I hit the deeplink with console:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://www.example.com/"
```

But that's not the case (only able to open with browser) when I only set the pattern and call "www.example.com".

Is there any jetpack navigation-ish way to support deep-linking without "/" in the deeplink pattern? Thank you

Comment: Are you trying to use `www.example.com` in your `adb shell am start`? What happens when you actually test it in a browser on your device?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use https://www.example.com with my adb. The same thing happened when I open it via clicking a url link.