# Is there a way to make a catch-all parameter in a route when using jetpack compose navigation?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking

I am trying to make an app to display the uri which is used to open it through a deep link. It seems to crash whenever I pass in data that contains a "/" though.

Is there a way to define my route in a way, that it just consumes all the data after a given point in the path?

Example: Assuming I have the deep link `myDisplayApp://showContent/{content}`, is there any way to modify it so it takes arbitrary strings, even ones containing a `/` after `showContent/`?

I already saw these posts, but they just provide a workaround, not really a solution:

- [Passing URL as a parameter to Jetpack Compose Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950770/passing-url-as-a-parameter-to-jetpack-compose-navigation)
- [How to enable jetpack deeplink without a slash "/" in the deeplink pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62978023/how-to-enable-jetpack-deeplink-without-a-slash-in-the-deeplink-pattern)

I would like to show whatever is sent in the deep link without being able to control what is being sent to the app.

It feels like most web-app-frameworks provide this functionality, which is especially necessary for error handeling in case of an unknown route.

Is this possible using Jetpack Compose Navigation? How?